# ¿Porque mi MV no detecta el DNS de otra MV?

Tags: dns

Estoy en una máquina con Elementary OS Loki y el DNS de mis máquinas virtuales no sirve
Mi server DNS lo tengo en una mv con Windows Server 2003 y mis clientes están con Windows XP igual en una mv.
Configuro correctamente todo para que mi servidor DNS funcione correctamente,cuando hago el ping a mi nombre de dominio desde el server, todo funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo hago desde mi cliente a mi server no funciona. También intento con la IP del servidor y si sirve. No se que pueda ser

Comment: Has comprobado que los clientes tengan configurado como servidor DNS al W2003 ?

Comment: Comprobaste que tengas bien configurado tu adaptadores de red?, estos deben estar en red interna para que se puedan comunicar entre si

Comment: Ya comprobé que los clientes estan configurados con el servidor DNS y también mis adaptadores de red que los tengo en red interna

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitar los resultados de un `nslookup`? También vendría bien un volcado completo de `ipconfig /all` para comprobar si ambos equipos tienen la misma configuración. ¿El servidor WS 2003 hace de controlador de dominio (DC) y los equipos inician sesión en él? ¿Usas el rol de servidor DNS del DC o el servidor DNS configurado de manera manual?